# matlab equality check going wrong. decides true on an arbitrary moment

Tags: matlab, equality

THE CODE:

```
function[E] = eig_noshift(A)
A_k = A;
for(i=0:inf)
    [Qk,Rk] = qr(A_k);
    A_k1 = Rk*Qk;

    diag(A_k1)
    diag(A_k)
    isequal(diag(A_k1),diag(A_k))
    if(isequal(diag(A_k1),diag(A_k)))
        break
    end
    A_k = A_k1;
end

E = diag(A_k);
```

I'm creating a matlab method that calculates a matrix' eigenvalues with the QR-algorithm. (which works) i'm trying to break the for loop if the next matrix diagonal is equal to the current diagonal (algorithm has converged)

When executing the algorithm I get following output:

```
>> eig_noshift(A0)
Warning: FOR loop index is too large. Truncating to 281474976710655. 
> In eig_noshift at 3 

ans =

    4.8419
    1.2591
   -0.0011


ans =

  -22.2000
  -14.6000
   42.9000


ans =

     0


ans =

    4.9434
    1.0611
    0.0954


ans =

    4.8419
    1.2591
   -0.0011


ans =

     0


ans =

    4.9881
    1.0123
    0.0996


ans =

    4.9434
    1.0611
    0.0954


ans =

     0


ans =

    4.9976
    1.0024
    0.1000


ans =

    4.9881
    1.0123
    0.0996


ans =

     0


ans =

    4.9995
    1.0005
    0.1000


ans =

    4.9976
    1.0024
    0.1000


ans =

     0


ans =

    4.9999
    1.0001
    0.1000


ans =

    4.9995
    1.0005
    0.1000


ans =

     0


ans =

    5.0000
    1.0000
    0.1000


ans =

    4.9999
    1.0001
    0.1000


ans =

     0


ans =

    5.0000
    1.0000
    0.1000


ans =

    5.0000
    1.0000
    0.1000


ans =

     0


ans =

    5.0000
    1.0000
    0.1000


ans =

    5.0000
    1.0000
    0.1000


ans =

     0

--- a few dozen more iterations that are the same ---


ans =

    5.0000
    1.0000
    0.1000


ans =

    5.0000
    1.0000
    0.1000


ans =

     0


ans =

    5.0000
    1.0000
    0.1000


ans =

    5.0000
    1.0000
    0.1000


ans =

     1
```

The 0/1 values are as you can see the truth value of checking the equality between the previous 2 vectors outputted. As you can see, the algo should have converged/stopped a long while ago, but didn't until some arbetrary moment. What am I doing wrong?

**SOLUTION:**

ofcourse I forgot to put matlab in format long and didn't think about it straight on. (I don't use matlab all that often) anyway the solution I have is adding a precision boundary to the method, resulting in following code:

```
function[E] = eig_noshift(A, prec)
A_k = A;
v_prec = [prec;prec;prec];
for(i=0:inf)
    [Qk,Rk] = qr(A_k);
    A_k1 = Rk*Qk;

    if(diag(A_k1) - diag(A_k) < v_prec)
        break
    end
    A_k = A_k1;
end

E = diag(A_k);
```

Method stops when asked precision has been reached. cheers!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The output does not include all digits. Print the difference instead: `diag(A_k1)-diag(A_k)`

Comment: thanks for reminding me to use format long and a precision parameter. problem solved :)